# Shorten the mysql case query

Tags: mysql, sql

I have written this query but it seems a very bad query,

```
select * from games_applied where  
 games_post_id='1126' and status != '4' and
 (status != '5' and rejected_status = '0' or status = '5' and rejected_status = '1');
```

How to make use of this case in a better way.

```
(status != '5' and rejected_status = '0' or status = '5' and rejected_status = '1')
```

should only display the rows which has **rejected_status = 1 and status = 5**
and should not display the rows which has **rejected_Status = 0 and status = 5**

Comment: Would you please give a small description that what you want to get as output? Please add table structure also so that it would be more helpful.

Comment: *but it seems a very bad query* - ***Why?***

Comment: @iamdave it seems to me as a bad query

Comment: @dude  Yes, we get that from your question.  But *why* does it seem a bad query?  What do you think is wrong with it?

Comment: @iamdave Its about the condition i have written

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not a major simplification, but it does remove the comparison to `4`.  However, this is how I would write the query:

```
select ga.*
from games_applied ga
where ga.games_post_id = 1126 and
      ( (ga.status not in (4, 5) and ga.rejected_status = 0) or
        (ga.status = 5 and ga.rejected_status = 1)
      );
```

Notes:

- The table has a meaningful table alias.
- All the column names are qualified.
- I assume that the numbers are really comparisons for numeric columns, so I removed the single quotes.
- I removed the comparison to "4".

Answer (score 1):

The only improvements that your query needs, is to encapsulate the two clauses on either side of your or statement. In other words, put your `status` and `rejected_status` check inside parentheses.

```
select 
    * 
from 
    games_applied 
where  
    games_post_id='1126' 
    and status != '4' 
    and
    (
        (status != '5' and rejected_status = '0') 
        or (status = '5' and rejected_status = '1')
    );
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the query hopefully it works as required :

```
select * from games_applied where  
games_post_id='1126' and status != '4' and case when status='5' then 
rejected_status='1' else rejected_status='0' end;
```